# Using array_keys to search a multidimensional array with a partial array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$testArray = array( 
                array(1,2,"file1.png"), 
                array(1,3,"file2.png"), 
                array(1,4,"file3.png")                    
              );

print_r (array_keys($testArray, array(1,3, "file2.png"))); // Works
print_r (array_keys($testArray, array(1,3))); // Does not work.
```

As shown in the code above, I'd like to be able to quickly find an array in a multidimensional array but only specify two of the values.

Comment: thats not how array keys works, array keys searches the key by value. array(1,3) is a different value than what $testArray contains. I don't believe theres a 'quick' way to do this without copying or manipulating the array values somehow.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Was just wondering if there was a way to potentially use a search value like (1,3, wildcard)

Comment: So as the final result you actually want the keys or just true/false if it is there?

Comment: What I need is to see if an x,y coordinate is in the array so I can find the file to use in that location for a map. So if 1,2 is in the array then I want to get the key so I can get the value "file1.png" to display on the map in that location. I'm currently using the looping method that's been shown elsewhere on this site but I'm wondering if there is a possible faster alternate method.

Comment: A comment on my answer may work to match them in order using `array_intersect_assoc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to filter the testArray down to those number of keys using array_map, then use array_search to get the key.

```
$testArray = array( 
                array(1,2,"file1.png"), 
                array(1,3,"file2.png"), 
                array(1,4,"file3.png")                    
              );

$search = [1,3];
$filtered = array_map(function ($item) use ($search){
    return array_slice($item, 0, count($search));
}, $testArray);

$key = array_search($search, $filtered);
if ($key !== false){
    print_r($testArray[$key]);
} else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array by testing which ones contain the values by computing the intersection and then get those keys:

```
$keys = array_keys(array_filter($testArray,
                                function($v) {
                                    return count(array_intersect([1,3], $v)) == 2;
                                }));
```

You can extend it with a search `$s` variable:

```
$s = [1,3];
$keys = array_keys(array_filter($testArray,
                                function($v) use($s) {
                                    return count(array_intersect($s, $v)) == count($s);
                                }));
```

This will return the keys for any sub array that contains `[1,3]`, `[3,1]` or even `[3,"file2.png",1]`, order is irrelevant.

To check them in order:

```
$s = [1,3];
$keys = array_keys(array_filter($testArray,
                                function($v) use($s) {
                                    return count(array_intersect_assoc($s, $v)) == count($s);
                                }));
```

Comment: search values of [1,3] and [3,1] would have the same results in this case

Comment: Yes, if that's not what they want then they can use something else.

Comment: Also just of note, [3, 3] would return anything with a 3 in it

Comment: Yes, but `array_intersect` would only return `1` 3 and the `count` of `1` is NOT `== 2`

Comment: I like this answer also, but I'm going to pick the other one because it let's me look for exactly what I need. This answer was very helpful in extending my PHP knowledge though so I appreciate it and your time.

Comment: If you change the array_intersect to array_intersect_assoc then it would achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Your array data

```
$testArray = [
    [1, 2, 'file1.png'], 
    [1 ,3, 'file2.png'], 
    [1 ,4, 'file3.png']                    
];
```

Specify what your search match conditions into an array

```
$matching = [1, 3];
```

Loop through your array data to find matches using [array_intersect_assoc()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect_assoc.asp) which compares values and keys between two arrays. Store the actual found key and its values into a new array.

```
foreach ($testArray as $index => $contents) {
    if (array_intersect_assoc($matching, $contents) == $matching) {
        $found[$index] = $contents;
    }
}
```

Display the results

```
echo '<pre>';
!empty($found) ? print_r($found) : print_r('not found');
```

Comment: There is no need for any counting.  https://3v4l.org/NfC60

Comment: @mickmackusa Counting removed.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your data and slice each triplet, taking the first two items, and compare these to your needle.  Return the file given a match.

```
<?php
$data = array( 
    array(1, 2, "file1.png"), 
    array(1, 3, "file2.png"), 
    array(1, 4, "file3.png")
);

$get_file_from_coords = function(array $coords) use ($data) {
    foreach($data as $v) {
        if (array_slice($v, 0, 2) == $coords) {
            return $v[2];
        }
    }
};

echo $get_file_from_coords([1, 3]);
```

Output:

```
file2.png
```

(Note: If you have more than one file associated with your co-ordinate pair you'll need to adapt the code to return an array of matches.)

You don't necessarily need to slice or do anything fancy here.  You can just compare like so:

```
[$v[0], $v[1]] == $coords
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  (...and curly braces to meet modern/professional/psr standards)  Why not use `[]` instead of `null` as the default.